# A Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem question our group could not solve

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\delta_x$ denote the point mass at $x$, i.e. $$\delta_x(E) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in E \\
0& x \not\in E 
\end{cases} 
$$
Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mu$ be the Borel measure $\mu = m +\delta_0 + \delta_1$. Let $\lambda$ be the signed Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all continuously differentiable functions $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with bounded support we have
$$
\int f(x) \ d\lambda = \int_0^1 f'(x) x^2 \ dx.
$$
Prove that $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and find the Radon--Nikodym derivative $d\lambda/d\mu$.

---

My best idea so far: Suppose $\mu(E) = 0$. Then $m(E) = 0$ and $\delta_0 = \delta_1 = 0$, so $0 \not\in E$ and $1 \not\in E$. Then it would be tempting to do something like
$$
\lambda(E) = \int_E \ d\lambda = \int \chi_E(x) \ d \lambda = \int_0^1 0 \ d \lambda = 0,
$$
to conclude that $\lambda \ll m$, but of course characteristic functions are not $C^1$ on their support. Perhaps there is some way of adapting this idea?

Comment: *Hint.* For any $f\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$, integration by parts shows that $$\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)x^2\,\mathrm{d}x=f(1) - \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) (2x \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x))\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Now can you realize the right-hand side as the form $\int f(x)\,\lambda(\mathrm{d}x)$ for some $\lambda\ll\mu$?

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice observation. It seems the proof you are hinting towards is quite distinct in flavour from Kavi's below?

Comment: Indeed my comment is hinting how to find an explicit form of $\lambda$, from which all the other assertions can be deduced.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Restricted to $\mathbb R \setminus \{0,1\}$ the measures $\lambda $ and $m$ coincide. Hence it is enough to show that $\lambda \{0\}=0$ and $\lambda \{1\}=0$. Let $E=\mathbb R \setminus (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ where $0 <\epsilon <1$. There exists a smooth function $f$ such that $f$ and $f'$ bounded by constants independent of $\epsilon$, $f(x)=0$ for $|x| <\epsilon$ and $1$ for $|x| >2\epsilon$. Now show that the right side of the given equation tends to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. This gives $\lambda \{0\}=0$ . Similarly, $\lambda \{1\}=0$